# ¿Cómo capturar dos botones con un único TextView

Tags: android

Tengo dos botones y quiero que al clicar a cada uno me lance una otra actividad, pero mostrando un mensaje diferente implementando un único Text View.
No logro hacerlo con un único TextView.

Mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,thirdActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("str", "check");
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txt.setText("Sin");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,thirdActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("str2", "check2");
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txt.setText("Con");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
            }
        });

    }
```

En la otra actividad tengo esto:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("str");

txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
txt.setText(""+message);
```

Comment: ¿En qué layout de qué Activity tienes definido R.id.textView2? Si es en thirdActivity, no puedes acceder a él en MainActivity para ejecutar el setText, lo tienes que hacer en thirdActivity, que parece que ya lo haces... Por otro lado, pulsando ambos botones lanzas la misma thridActivity pero en cada una creas un parámetro con nombre distinto str y str2, pero luego solo has puesto el código en el que extraes str, y no str2. ¿No debería ser en ambos casos el mismo nombre (str por ejemplo) con diferentes valores? Explica mejor qué quieres conseguir porque no se entiende.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. Como ya te dijo @SuperG280, en los `intent` debes dar el mismo identificador al dato que mandas: o `str` o `str2` para que sea más fácil recuperarlo en la otra `Activity`. Luego tienes un lío tremendo nombrando tus objetos que no ayuda para nada. Por ejemplo, a `btn2` le asignas el `R.id.button3`, y en el listener,  usas `btn3` para llamar a `SecondActivity`... etc. Todo eso crea confusión. Acostumbra a nombrar los objetos por lo que hacen o por lo que representan en lugar de llamarles `Objeto1, Objeto2, Objeto999` llega un momento que estás perdido en tu propia casa.

Comment: He puesto la key "str" y "str2" porque quiero que pulsando cada botón, que me salga un mensaje diferente, pero en el mismo textview2 que tengo en el thirdpary.  En la actividad "third party", sé que solamente tengo un solo setText para obtener el valor de "str". Lo que pasa es que también quiero obtener el contenido de "str2", pero solamente tengo un solo findById(R.Id.Textview2) y no puedo sacar contenido diferente. Clicando a los dos botones, siempre obtengo el mismo contenido, cosa que yo no quiero. No sé si me he explicado bien. Espero que sí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas enviando 2 diferentes valores

```
 intent.putExtra("str", "check");
```

y

```
 intent.putExtra("str2", "check2");
```

pero solo estas obteniendo uno de ellos de acuerdo a su llave que es "str":

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("str");
```

Te sugiero que en ambos valores que envies configures la misma llave "str", con esto solucionaras el problema:

```
    ...
    ...
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,thirdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("str", "check");
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            txt.setText("Sin");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,thirdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("str", "check2"); 
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            txt.setText("Con");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Lo he probado y la app se me cuelga. Que tengo que poner en la ThirdActivity para mostrar el texto?

Comment: @dahchourayoub es importante revisar el LogCat puede ser que esto este correcto pero exista algún problema en tu thirdActivity, que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya lo tengo arreglado. El problema era que yo ya pedía la "str" desde thirdactivity mediante la key. Solución: Simplemente borrando los setText de arriba. Gracias por iluminarme. Es que acabo de empezar con Android y ni siquiera he utilizado el logcat. Ahora cada vez que me pase algo, lo miraré.

Comment: ok , los TextView solo existen en MainActivity. Es super importante el uso del LogCat cuando desarrollas en Android, eso te ayudará a resolver rápidamente los problemas, saludos! :-)